# Is there a way to create a char array of the same character based on how many letters there are in a string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to create a hangman game in Java, and I was wondering if there was a way to create a `char array` of the same character based on how many letters there are in a string.
For example, if the user inputs a `5 letter word`, then a `char array` is created with `5 underscores`.

This is what I've tried so far to no avail:

```
    System.out.println("Enter a word to guess");
    String wordToGuess = input.nextLine();

    String array[] = {"_", "_", "_",};
    char underscore[] = array.toCharArray();
```

The error message I get is:

```
Cannot invoke toCharArray() on the array type String[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//creates a char array the same size as the word the user has given
char[] underscore = new char[wordToGuess.length()];
//fills all the items in the underscore array with '_' character 
Arrays.fill(underscore, '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is the following

```
char[] chars = new char[userinput.length()] ;
Arrays.fill(chars, '_') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] sArray = {"_", "_", "_",};
String s = "";
for (String n:sArray)
s+= n;
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Including an explanation would improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The toCharArray() method is only available on String, not on String[]. That is why the error occurs.

You could join all pieces of the array, then convert to characters. E.g. `String.join(“”, array).toCharArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the string and manage this by turning your text into an *CHAR ARRAY*, as the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "This Is Test";
    int stringLength = testString.length(); //Maybe you can use this.
    char[] arrayName = testString.toCharArray(); //And here you can manage your array

    for (int i = 0; i<=testString.length()) {
        System.out.println(char[i]);
    }
}
```